# How to add another corresponding author to an Elsevier paper in Neptune?

Tags: author

How do you add another corresponding author to an Elsevier paper in Neptune while editing the proof of your paper?

Code for one corresponding author:

```
\author{First Author} 
\cormark[1] 
\cortext[1]{\COR}

\author{Second Author}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Are you trying to ask and answer your own question? If so, question posts and answer posts should be separate—you'll want to post your answer in the "Your Answer" box below, then edit your question post to remove the answer part.

Answer (score 0):

Code for two corresponding authors:

```
\author{First C. Author}
\cormark[1]
\cortext[1]{\CORS}

\author{Second C. Author}
\cormark[1]
```

\cormark[1] places "*" after the author's name.

\cortext[1]{\COR} provides the text "* Corresponding Author."

\cortext[1]{\CORS} provides the text "* Corresponding Authors."